# Bottom border gradient support for safari browser

Tags: css, browser, safari, gradient, compatibility

Is there any way to support bottom border gradient for safari browser, only safari browser don't support this

```css
 h2 {
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
 h2::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em;
    width: 80%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #CA49D9, #2452A2);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h2>How it works</h2>
```

Here is the safari output

[image]

Comment: If you change the height of the `::after` to 0, does the result look more like you want? And/or try to set the border widths explicitly.

Comment: Chrome and firefox browser okay just safari looks like a screen shot ! an unexpected square box !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added other border properties (left, right and top) to 0px and it worked in all browser.
Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/1da8nx5g/1/

```css
h2 {
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
 h2::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em;
    width: 80%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #CA49D9, #2452A2);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h2>How it works</h2>
```

Comment: @Momin sure..i checked and verified in version 11.1.1

Comment: Here its look same as it was before ! I test from safari (iMac) version 10.1

Comment: @Momin oh! its working fine in the mentioned browser version(MacBook Pro)

Comment: Yeah Its Working ! Some cache problem on safari browser. Thanks

Comment: @Momin happy to know it helped you!